# Is Apple's Device Enrollment Program (DEP) tied into the OSX Installer, Hard Drive or Machine?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, automated-device-enrollment

My case is I bought a macbook off eBay, reformated the SSD inside it to High Sierra then transfered the SSD to an older Macbook and that's when I started getting the DEP notifications. The older Macbook previously never had the notifications.

So my guess is the DEP either came from the OSX installer I used or the SSD?

Comment: Which Mac is getting DEP notifications? What model and year is the affected Mac according to this guide - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300

Answer (score 1):

DEP follows the machine, not the installer or drive.

Apple doesn’t have a neat article for this like it does for iPhone or Apple Watch.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208855